# Multidimensional array in PHP 5

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, php-5.5

I have a simple question, but I can´t do this working.

I have this multidimensional array in my system:

```
array (size=5)
  'id_cli' => string '13' (length=2)
  'login_cli' => string 'userlogin' (length=10)
  'senha_cli' => string 'userpass' (length=3)
  'cli_nome' => string 'username' (length=16)
  'cart' => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 48
      'tamanho' => string 'G' (length=1)
      'qtde' => int 1
```

This array is saved in my `$_SESSION`. The cart key is to save my cart products. In the above example, I have 1 product.

I need to save new products inside my session array cart, but I can´t do that. Every new product I try to insert, is saved over the first one, not inserted.

I am doing this:

- Declaring my cart array:

  ```
  if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
  {
      $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
  }
  ```
- Inserting a new product in my session:

  ```
  $_SESSION['cart'] = array("id" => $id_produto, "tamanho" => $tamanho_produto, "qtde" => 1);
  ```

But it is not working. What can I do to insert new arrays inside my `$_SESSION['cart']` ?

And what I need to do to delete an specific product inside this `$_SESSION['cart']` array ?

Thanks,
Marcelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert new products as an array OF an array.  Try it like so :

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array("id" => $id_produto, "tamanho" => $tamanho_produto, "qtde" => 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $newElement);` to insert array element to existing array.

Alternate way of doing this is `$_SESSION['cart'][] = $newElement;`

To remove specific element you can use below logic

```
 $arrayKey=array_search($arrayKeyName,$_SESSION['cart']);
 if($arrayKey!==false) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$arrayKey]);
```

Alternate way of doing this

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $v) {
  if($v == $arrayKeyName)
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$k]);
}
```